# cURL error couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

I have this code here to get the content of xml file from a different server.
And I used `curl_error()` to catch errors and I got **Couldn't resolve host 'web.test.net'**

```
$xmlpath = 'https://web.test.net/xml/products.xml';
// Sorry I have to not use real URL
$curl_open = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_open, CURLOPT_URL, $xmlpath);
ob_start();
$result = curl_exec($curl_open);
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$e= array();
```

I've read that DNS configuration on the server might be the cause. If possible, can someone please tell me the area that needs to be configured? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the server and your host exists? Can you download the file from a browser?

You could try pinging the server using:
ping web.test.net

Or try doing an nslookup web.test.net, this will ask the DNS controller your server is using for the IP address of web.test.net

Comment: When i used my terminal for a ping, i got the same error that the could not be resolved. Are you working local and is the link correct?

Comment: No problems when I ping. I can also see the the XML content when I access the URL using browser.